# How to load all the files of a S3 folder using COPY Command in redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, manifest.json, amazon-connect

So far i have done it with single folder as `COPY Command` pull the data of files and load it into redshift table using the `prefix`, now i want to pull the identical data from two different folders/buckets and load it into redshift table.
I have used this:

```
copy MyTable
FROM 's3://my-bucket/connect/Reports' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::my-role:role/RedshiftRoleForS3'
csv
null as '\000'
IGNOREHEADER 1;
```

i have tried manifest but the problem of manifest is i am unable to fetch/pull the data with prefix.

```
{
  "entries": [
    {"url":"s3://my-bucket1/connect/Reports", "mandatory":true},
    {"url":"s3://my-bucket2/connect/Reports", "mandatory":true}
  ]
}

copy myTable
FROM 's3://my-bucket1/connect/ABC.manifest' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::my-role:role/RedshiftForS3'
manifest
csv
null as '\000'
IGNOREHEADER 1;
```

because i have to pull all the data of files the folder `Reports` contains.
How to achieve it? any Solution please? How can we use the `Prefix in Manifest` method?

Answer (score 0):

From [Using a manifest to specify data files - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/loading-data-files-using-manifest.html):

> The URL in the manifest must specify the bucket name and full object path for the file, not just a prefix.

So, it does not seem possible to specify **paths** in a Redshift manifest file.

Comment: Yeah, that's the restriction, i just wanted to go beyond of this restriction. Thank you.